# How do I make a long sequence of chained as_ref().unwrap()s more meaningful?

Tags: error-handling, rust

What's the idiomatic way in Rust to re-order sequence on `as_ref.unwrap()` in something more meaningful? I have a set of values returned from a database and handle them in a following way:

```
pub fn get_results(result: &Result<Option<Vec<Node>>, error::Error>) -> &Vec<Vec<Value>> {
    &result
        .as_ref()
        .unwrap()
        .as_ref()
        .unwrap()
        .first()
        .unwrap()
        .series
        .as_ref()
        .unwrap()
        .first()
        .as_ref()
        .unwrap()
        .values
}
```

Maybe I can iterate with higher-over function or something else?

Comment: I'd say [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then)s and/or [`?`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html)s.

Comment: Look strange to use `as_ref()` in this context a [mcve] would be appreciate.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, `Use of undeclared type or module \`error\`` / `cannot find type \`Node\` in this scope` / `cannot find type \`Value\` in this scope`. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want this boilerplate, you can add more boilerplate to not see it, with the try operator (`?`). See this proof of concept:

```
#![feature(try_trait)]

use std::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError;

impl Error for MyError {
    //
}

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        write!(f, "MyError")
    }
}

impl From<std::option::NoneError> for MyError {
    fn from(_: std::option::NoneError) -> MyError {
        MyError
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a std::io::Error> for MyError {
    fn from(_: &'a std::io::Error) -> MyError {
        MyError
    }
}

fn foo(i: &Result<Option<i32>, std::io::Error /* for example */>) -> Result<&i32, MyError> {
    Ok(i.as_ref()?.as_ref()?)
}
```

Unfortunately, I think that you cannot remove the `as_ref` calls.